# Multiple static addresses on same interface via Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

So in trying to convert manual installation instructions to Vagrant on setting up the VM, I'm stumped on how I make the `/etc/network/interfaces` file have the following:

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.56.101
netmask 255.255.255.0

auto eth1:1
iface eth1:1 inet static
address 192.168.56.102
netmask 255.255.255.0

auto eth1:2
iface eth1:2 inet static
address 192.168.56.103
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

These interfaces are all using a host-only adapter on the VM in VirtualBox.

I know I can just create three separate adapters and use the same host-only adapter doing something like this:

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.56.101"
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.56.102"
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.56.103"
```

But that doesn't obviously match the above file. I'd rather not have some hacky solution of rewriting /etc/network/interfaces on boot-up/shutdown, but I can't seem to get Vagrant to work and can't find anything else on it beyond very simple tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure you can do that just using default network config.

I tried a few options using some parameters as

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.101", :device => "eth1", :adapter => 1, :netmask => "255.255.255.0"
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.102", :device => "eth1:1", :adapter => 1, :netmask => "255.255.255.0"
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.103", :device => "eth1:2", :adapter => 1, :netmask => "255.255.255.0"
```

but this will either VM will not boot or each interface has its own interface.

Then looking at https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/public_network.html / DISABLE AUTO-CONFIGURATION, you can do the following

```
# manual ip
config.vm.network "public_network", auto_config: false
config.vm.provision "shell",
  run: "always",
  inline: "ifconfig eth1 192.168.50.101 netmask 255.255.255.0 up"
config.vm.provision "shell",
  run: "always",
  inline: "ifconfig eth1:1 192.168.50.102 netmask 255.255.255.0 up"
config.vm.provision "shell",
  run: "always",
  inline: "ifconfig eth1:2 192.168.50.103 netmask 255.255.255.0 up"
```

when running `ifconfig -a` on the VM you get

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:e5:fe:e1
          inet addr:172.16.42.238  Bcast:172.16.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fee5:fee1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:766 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:489 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:83256 (83.2 KB)  TX bytes:69904 (69.9 KB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:e5:fe:eb
          inet addr:192.168.50.101  Bcast:192.168.50.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fee5:feeb/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:125 errors:0 dropped:20 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:17 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:10180 (10.1 KB)  TX bytes:1478 (1.4 KB)

eth1:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:e5:fe:eb
          inet addr:192.168.50.102  Bcast:192.168.50.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

eth1:2    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:e5:fe:eb
          inet addr:192.168.50.103  Bcast:192.168.50.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```